# Latitude and Longitude coordinates in R

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a column of combined latitude and longitude coordinates in the following format:

```
coordinates
(-73.2566,44.51513)
```

I am trying to  get the format

```
lat     long
73.2566  44.51512
```

I know this seems like a relatively simple question but I cannot seem to find a solution.  I have tried using the gsub() function but that does not get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: use `pattern="\\(|\\"`, then `replacement = ""` for gsub, then `strsplit` by `","`.

Comment: as an aside (and because you've tagged this question with `google-maps`) I've built the [googleway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/googleway.pdf) package for accessing Google Maps APIs through R. See [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/vignettes/googleway-vignette.html) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> library(stringr)
> library(magrittr)
> "(-73.2566, 44.51513)" %>% # take coord as string
+   str_replace_all("[()]", "") %>% # replace parantheses
+   str_split_fixed(", ", n=2) %>% # split up based on comma and space after
+   as.data.frame %>% # turn this to a data frame
+   transmute(lat=V1, long=V2) # rename the variables
       lat      long
1 -73.2566  44.51513
```

If you have a vector of these values, it could easily be adapted by doing this `for (i in coords)` where the `data.frame` at the end would be repeatedly added to the dataset using something like `bind_rows`.

Comment: Thank you this was extremely helpful I knew it was simpler than I thought it was haha.

Answer (score 2):

try with this simple function (need use google api):

```
google_api <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
geocode <- function(address, verbose=FALSE) {
library(httr)
r <- GET(google_api, query=list(address=address))
stop_for_status(r)
result <- content(r)
first <- result$results[[1]]
df <- as.data.frame(list(lat=first$geometry$location$lat, 
lon=first$geometry$location$lng))
return(df)
}

#example
geocode("Suzhou New Matro")
       lat      lon
1 31.31015 120.6221
```

Using google api the function `geocode()` returns for each city the coordinates in the format you require

Comment: I was more interested in using the points already provided but thank you for this helpful function will definitely use next time I only have addresses.

Comment: Lorenzo, you genius!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a wee bit too simple but

```
> coordinates=c(-73.2566,44.51513)
> coordinates
[1] -73.25660  44.51513
> lat=coordinates[1]
> lat
[1] -73.2566
> long=coordinates[2]
> long
[1] 44.51513
```

There is a ggmap package   at https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/ggmap/ggmapCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the great cheatsheet saved it to my desktop for future reference!